# Why is this causing a server error

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am try to publish posts created by the usernames in the following array each users has. I am adding this to the [microscope practice app](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope) The error is I20140826-20:31:53.452(-4)?     at Meteor.publish.Comments.find.postId [as _handler] (app/server/publications.js:2:13). Thanks in advanced here is the code.

publications.js
The loop is supposed to publish posts made by each username in the following array.

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(options) {
for (u=0;u<this.user.profile.following.length;u++) {
    f=profile.following[u].text();
    return Posts.find({username:f}, options);
  }
});
```

The Routes it will affect

Controllers

```
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'postsList',
  increment: 5, 
  limit: function() { 
  return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment; 
  },
  findOptions: function() {
    return {sort: this.sort, limit: this.limit()};
  },
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
  },
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
  },
  data: function() {
    var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.limit();
    return {
      posts: this.posts(),
      nextPath: hasMore ? this.nextPath() : null
    };
  }
});

NewPostsListController = PostsListController.extend({
  sort: {submitted: -1, _id: -1},
  nextPath: function() {
    return Router.routes.newPosts.path({postsLimit: this.limit() + this.increment})
  }
});

BestPostsListController = PostsListController.extend({
  sort: {votes: -1, submitted: -1, _id: -1},
  nextPath: function() {
    return Router.routes.bestPosts.path({postsLimit: this.limit() + this.increment})
  }
});
```

Router map

```
  this.route('newPosts', {
    path: '/new/:postsLimit?',
    controller: NewPostsListController
  });

  this.route('bestPosts', {
    path: '/best/:postsLimit?',
    controller: BestPostsListController
  });
```

Comment: you need to work on this question, for starters, make it a question, give the error, also that very first for loop? what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I think the problem comes from calling the method `text` on `profile.following[u]` : there is no such method, `profile.following[u]` is probably a `String` so you get its value simply by referencing it.

Comment: Ok I removed it no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your publish function is wrong, are you aware that your loop is useless because it is exiting upon encountering the first return ?

Even if you were aggregating the cursors accumulated in the loop this wouldn't work because at the moment a publish function can only return multiple cursors from DIFFERENT collections.

You need to use the appropriate mongo selector here, which is probably `$in`.

Also, `profile.following` is not even defined in the publish function, and iterating over an array is done by checking the iterator variable against the array length (`profile.following.length`), or better yet using `Array.prototype.forEach` or `_.each`.

I think this is what you're trying to do :

```
Meteor.publish("posts",function(options){
  if(!this.userId){
    this.ready();
    return;
  }
  var currentUser=Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  return Posts.find({
    username:{
      $in:currentUser.profile.following
    }
  },options);
});
```

You should definitely read resources about JavaScript itself before digging any further in Meteor, if you're following the `Discover Meteor` book I think they provide some good JS tutorials for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for try but your code returns the same set of errors. Also `Meteor.user();` can not be used in publish functions.

Comment: Oops, forgot about that, I just edited my code. I messed up with `$in` syntax too, now it should be ok.